# Template formatting

Tags: jquery, templates

I'm trying to figure out how I can format a value with [jquery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

One of the values is a bool which I would like to convert to a string. I tried:

```
{IsVisible?'x':'-'}
```

which didn't work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work fine (provided it's prefixed with a `$`):

```
${IsVisible ? 'x' : '-'}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/fSVfU/).

Comment: @jgauffin: haha! I've just tried loads of different things and arrived back at the code I thought we both had originally, which works ;)